# HTML onClick go to another div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button on my webpage which when onClick I want it to show another div. However when I click the button it will flash in the url that it went to the correct div but then it will immediately redirect back to the main div, #home.

Code for button:

```
<input type="button" class="flip" value="Redirect To Div" onClick="window.location='#targetDiv'" />
```

When I click the the button the url will flash:

www.XXXXX.com/#targetDiv

Then go immediately to www.XXXXX.com/#home

Any ideas why it won't display the div?

Thanks

Comment: You're definitely not showing all your code. I've just written this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/W2r44/) to test out your input and it works fine. You have *something else* that's directing it to the `#home` route

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like your form has

```
       action=""
```

or

```
       action="#home"
```

instead of onclick call a function

```
      onclick="mylinkfunction()"
```

...

```
     <script type-"text/javascript">

       function mylinkfunction(e) {

       window.location.href="#targetDiv";

       /* need to stop the form sending of the form

        UPDATE as comment: This may not be exactly correct syntax 
        for stopping a form , look up preventing form submission */

       e.preventDefault();
       e.stopPropagation(); 

       }

     </script>
```

or if your form is irrelevent set it's action and remove the javascript allogether

```
     <form action="#targetDiv" method="get">
     <input type="submit" value="go"/>
     </form>
```

but then all you would need is actually this ..

```
    <a href="#targetDiv">click me</a>
```

if by "go to another div" you mean jump and scroll the page to a new location it is actually an anchor you need to go to

```
        <a name="targetDiv"/>
```

Comment: I tried this but it does the same thing. Still redirects immediately.

Comment: hi, I may not have the right syntax for preventing the form submission there, but hope explains the concept. updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Reusable function to go to a particular div or section with href:

```
const dynamicHrefSetter = (href: string) => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') window.location.href = `#${href}`;
};
```